# Convert a hash into another hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a hash of strings

```
navigable_objects = { 'Dashboard' => root_path,
                      'Timesheets' => timesheets_path,
                      'Clients' => clients_path,
                      'Projects' => projects_path, 
                    }
```

I want to convert them into another hash where the key is again the key, but the value is either the string 'active' or empty string depending on whether the current controller name contains the key.

For example, lets say that the current controller name is "ClientsController".  The result I should get is:

```
{ 'Dashboard' => '',
  'Timesheets' => '',
  'Clients' => 'active',
  'Projects' => ''
}
```

Here is how I am currently doing it:

```
active = {}

navigable_objects.each do |name, path|
  active[name] = (controller.controller_name.include?(name)) ? 'active' : '')
end
```

I feel that while this works, there is a better way to do this in Ruby, possibly using `inject` or `each_with_objects`?

Comment: I would like to point out that while there are other solutions (all the posted ones so far are good), there's nothing particularly wrong with the way you did it originally.

Comment: I think the thing that irks me the most is the hash declaration at the top, and your each_with_objects solution pretty much solves that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*NOTE: I already answered but I'm posting this as a separate answer because it's better for your specific situation, but my other answer still has merit on its own.*

Since you're not using the values of the hash at all, you *can* use `each_with_object`:

```
navigable_objects.keys.each_with_object({}) { |k,h| h[k] = controller.controller_name.include?(k) ? 'active' : '' }
```

Or more verbosely:

```
new_hash = navigable_objects.keys.each_with_object({}) do |key, hash|
   hash[key] = controller.controller_name.include?(key) ? 'active' : ''
end
```

If your result was based on the values too, then my other solution would work whereas this one wouldn't.

Answer (score 7):

*UPDATE: I posted another answer that I think is better for your situation. I'm leaving this one un-edited though because it has merit on its own for similar problems.*

Here's the way I'd do it:

```
Hash[*navigable_objects.map{ |k,v| [k, controller.controller_name.include?(k) ? 'active' : ''] }.flatten]
```

You can run `map` on a hash that gets key and value pairs as input to the block. Then you can construct pairs of key/values into arrays as the output. Finally, Running `Hash[*key_value_pairs.flatten]` is a nice trick to turn it back into a hash. This works because you can pass an array of arguments to the `Hash[]` constructor to generate a hash (`Hash[1, 2, 3, 4]` => `{ 1 => 2, 3 => 4 }`). And `flatten` turns the key value pairs into an array, and `*` operator turns an array into a list of arguments.

Here's a verbose version in case you want to see more clearly what's going on:

```
key_value_pairs = navigable_objects.map do |key, value|
    new_value = controller.controller_name.include?(k) ? 'active' : ''
    [key, new_value]
end

new_hash = Hash[*key_value_pairs.flatten]
```

Update: This above is compatible with ruby 1.8. As Andrew pointed out in the comments:

> In 1.9 you don't need the * or flatten as Hash[] takes key-value array
>   pairs

Comment: In 1.9 you don't need the `*` or `flatten` as [`Hash[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) takes key-value array pairs.

Answer (score 4):

Since Ruby 2.0, there is to_h:

```
navigable_objects.map do |name, path|
  [name, controller.controller_name.include?(name)) ? 'active' : '']
end.to_h
```

I don't think it's very efficient, but for small Hashes it's an elegant way.

Answer (score 1):

There are many many ways to accomplish this. This is just the way I'd do it.

With `inject`

```
active = navigable_objects.inject({}) do |h, obj|
  h[obj[0]] = controller.controller_name.include?(obj[0]) ? 'active' : ''
  h
end
```

When you call `inject` on a hash, the block is passed the thing you are injecting into (in this case a hash) and an array with the first element being the key and the last element being the value.

Comment: [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) is better here as you don't have to erroneously return the same hash reference every time `:)`

Comment: never used `each_with_object`, I could just `h.merge({key => val})`

Comment: Nah; `each_with_object` is [more typing and slower than `inject` (or `tap`)](http://phrogz.net/tap-vs-each_with_object).